# Line breaks in LESS

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to tell LESS to ignore deleting line breaks in compiled CSS in order to have a cleaner and more readable CSS?

And is it possible to tell LESS to keep single line CSS rules as they were originally instead of inserting line breaks between each selector, example:

LESS:

```
html,body,div,span { ... }
```

Compiled CSS:

```
html,
body,
div,
span {
...
}
```

Comment: I simply prefer to use non-minified LESS on development time. You can better use minified less compiled css file on production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this cannot be easily done. [Looking into the source of the LESS compiler](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/bin/lessc), there are some options that could be used to customize this behaviour (e.g. `max_line_len`), but none that would affect this behaviour.

I think you need to either find a way to customize the LESS compiler or find out an alternative compiler implementation for LESS that would allow this as a configuration. Either way, I'm not sure if its worth the trouble.

Also, to be honest, I personally like the way LESS uses line breaks. It's much more readable and encourages you to apply rules in the simplest possible fashion to keep number of lines low.